# Converting String to Double for use in LatLng/Google Maps

Tags: android, string, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to convert a String value into a LatLng value for use in a GoogleMaps fragment in an Android app.  The string value will likely come in the form of "-45.654765, 65.432892".

I've tried two different ways of doing this, and both have resulted in errors.  First, I've tried using split() and putting the results into a String[], then accessing each using parseDouble(), as follows:

```
String[] geo = GEO.split(",");
double lati = Double.parseDouble(geo[0]);
double lngi = Double.parseDouble(geo[1]);
LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);
```

This yields an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` caused by `double lati = Double.parseDouble(geo[0]);`.  I'm not really sure why.

I've also tried using StringTokenizer, as follows:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(GEO, ",");
String lat = tokens.nextToken();
String lng = tokens.nextToken();
double lati = Double.parseDouble(lat);
double lngi = Double.parseDouble(lng);
LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);
```

This yields a `NoSuchElementException` pointing to `String lng = tokens.nextToken();`.

In both cases, the String I am working on, `GEO`, is `public static final` and passed from another activity via intent, where it is currently just hardcoded as `"43.75,-70.15"`.

`LOCATION` is `public static` and is a LatLng variable initialized as `null`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  This seems really simple so I'm even more confused than usual...

EDIT:

The data originates in a different activity where it is passed via intent.  The activity that receives the intent has `GEO` defined as follows:

```
public static final String GEO = "geo";
```

And the intent from the previous activity puts geo in like this:

```
          bundle.putString(PlaceActivity.GEO, geo);
```

Comment: It seams to me that your problem is caused by GEO being equal to "". Could you include how GEO is set?

Comment: How can GEO be final and at the same time be passed from another activity via intent? Your GEO is never set to have any comma in it. Could you add some code on how GEO is set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have

```
String loc = getIntent().getExtras().getString(PlaceActivity.GEO);
String[] geo = loc.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a very basic `substring`:

```
int index = GEO.indexOf(",");
String lat = GEO.substring(0, index).trim();
String lng = GEO.substring(index+1).trim();
double lati = Double.parseDouble(lat);
double lngi = Double.parseDouble(lng);
LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);
```

Sorry, untested.